# Sum Manipulation to be less than a constant

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, summation, proof-writing

I'm stuck with some basic sum manipulation in the middle of a proof. We have that:

- All terms are non-negative.
- $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty x_i=1$ (and the same goes for $y_i).$

Is there a way to show $|\sum\limits_{i=1}^j (x_i^2-y_i^2)|\leq |\sum\limits_{i=1}^j x_i-y_i|K$ for some constant, $K$?

Comment: What are the  restrictions for the $y_i$?

Comment: $x^2-y^2$ is written as $(x-y)(x+y)$ , what is the maximum that $|x+y|$ can take ?

Comment: @Abra good hint, the OP should be able to derive a maximum for this using the assumptions and then use your hint to complete the proof.

Comment: @Abra That makes sense! The max value for $|x_i+y_i|$ is 1!

Comment: Therefore, it is less than when $K=j.$

Comment: It can be that $\sum_{i = 1}^j (x_i - y_i) = 0$ but $\sum_{i = 1}^j (x_i^2 - y_i^2) \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the $y_i$ are terms in the sum:
$$|\Sigma x_i^2 -y_i^2  |= |\Sigma (x_i+y_i)(x_i -y_i)| $$,

where $(x_i+y_i)<1+1 $ by nonegativity of the $x_i,y_i$......and the bound

$\Sigma x_i =1=\Sigma y_i $.
Can you take it from here?